# Runs two different commands from subprocess and capture the output of both the process Python

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I am trying to run two different commands using subprocess module of python and capture the output from them and print it to the console...

XY_thread = Thread(target = run_command_XY) 
TEXT_thread = Thread(target = run_command_text) 

XY_thread.start() 
TEXT_thread.start()

so, i get output from the XY_thread and not from the TEXT_thread.
When i interchange the threads and start TEXT_thread first, then only TEXT_thread output is being displayed..

Im struck here, please help. I'm i missing something here?

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread


def run_command_text():
    command = "SOME COMMAND"

    process_ = Popen(command.split(), stdout = PIPE, shell = False)

    prev_line = None
    retcode = process_.poll()

    while(process_.poll() == None):
        line_ = process_.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8')

        if "SOME CONDITION" in line_:
        # does some operation and fetches the text(no issues with this part)
            if text != "":
                print(text)         
                prev_line = line_

        if retcode is not None:
            break

def run_command_XY():
    command = "SOME COMMAND"


    process = Popen(command.split(), stdout = PIPE,  shell = False)
    retcode = process.poll()

    while(process.poll() == None):

        line = process.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8')
    # does some operation and fetches the X and Y(no issues with this part)
        print(X+"  "+Y)

        if retcode is not None:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # multiprocessor = list()

    XY_thread = Thread(target = run_command_XY)
    TEXT_thread = Thread(target = run_command_text)

    XY_thread.start()
    TEXT_thread.start()
```

So,  when i run these both the methods seperately, they do their work as expected but when i try to run they parallel and then print both the outputs, there seems to be an issue. 
(Please ignore indentation)

Comment: `target` must be a callable. Don't call it beforehand like `target=run_command_XY()`. Use `target=run_command_XY` instead.

Comment: @VikrantSharma Thanks for the reply. I've tried to do that but still the original problem persists.  Only XY_thread's output is being displayed on cmd

Comment: You should include some more code, to indicate what those two functions do, the prints in them, and your output as well.

Comment: @VikrantSharma updated the post, please check and let me know if i have done anything wrong.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation? It's all out of place. and provide something similar to what you want to achieve? A Minimum, Verifiable, Complete example. Possibly without "SOME COMMAND" and "SOME CONDITION". I'm starting to think the problem may not be with the Threads.

Comment: @VikrantSharma when i put the two methods in different modules and run them seperately, they seem to work fine. Only when i want to run them in a single module the problem seems to arise.

Comment: There are still syntax errors. The `break` statements are outside the loops. `text`, `X`, `Y` and your commands and conditions are still undefined.

Comment: @VikrantSharma yea i have done the edits, i hope you understand what im asking for and running this code isn't a good idea . All i'm asking is how to run concurrent processes and get output from them.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to provide a small example of running two threads and checking the output of a process in each of them. Both are doing the exact same thing at the moment but it should give you an idea.

```
import subprocess as sp
from threading import Thread

def func_x():
    cmd = 'python --version'
    for _ in range(5):
        proc = sp.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=sp.PIPE)
        proc.wait()
        result = proc.stdout.read()
        print('func_x:', result.decode('utf-8').strip())

def func_y():
    cmd = 'python --version'
    for _ in range(5):
        proc = sp.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=sp.PIPE)
        proc.wait()
        result = proc.stdout.read()
        print('func_y:', result.decode('utf-8').strip())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x_thread = Thread(target=func_x)
    y_thread = Thread(target=func_y)

    x_thread.start()
    y_thread.start()
```

Which outputs:

```
func_y: Python 3.5.2
func_x: Python 3.5.2
func_y: Python 3.5.2
func_x: Python 3.5.2
func_y: Python 3.5.2
func_x: Python 3.5.2
func_x: Python 3.5.2
func_y: Python 3.5.2
func_y: Python 3.5.2
func_x: Python 3.5.2
```